# What javascript modification is needed to ensure the play count of a video player won't increase after pressing pause, then play?

Tags: javascript, video, counter, playback, pause

I constructed some HTML and JavaScript code for a video player. It plays the video, but when I press pause, then press play again the play count increases. I only want the play count to increase after the song has finished playing. Below is the java script format. If HTML code is needed I will provide it. I'm just having trouble meeting the post requirements. I'm being told that I'm writing too much code. It is a simple video player though.

```
<script>
// JavaScript
const videoPlayer = document.querySelector('.video-player');
const videoElement = videoPlayer.querySelector('.video');
const playCountElement = videoPlayer.querySelector('.play-count');

let playCount = 0;

function updatePlayCount() {
    playCountElement.textContent = playCount + ' Plays';
}

function savePlayCount() {
    localStorage.setItem('playCount', playCount);
}

function loadPlayCount() {
    const storedPlayCount = localStorage.getItem('playCount');
    if (storedPlayCount !== null) {
        playCount = parseInt(storedPlayCount);
    }
}

function playVideo() {
    videoElement.play();
    playCount++;
    updatePlayCount();
    savePlayCount();
}

function pauseVideo() {
    videoElement.pause();
}

function togglePlayPause() {
    if (videoElement.paused) {
        playVideo();
    } else {
        pauseVideo();
    }
}

videoElement.addEventListener('ended', function () {
    videoElement.currentTime = 0; // Reset video to the beginning when it ends
    hasBeenPlayed = false; // Set hasBeenPlayed to false only when you want to reset play count after the video ends
    pauseVideo();
});

videoElement.addEventListener('play', function () {
    playCount++; // Increment play count when video starts playing
    updatePlayCount();
    savePlayCount();
});

videoPlayer.addEventListener('click', togglePlayPause);

// Load the initial play count when the page loads
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    loadPlayCount();
    updatePlayCount();
});


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try having a variable to note if it's a "first time playing" as...

**(1)** Replace `let playCount = 0;` with the following:

```
let playCount;
let is_FirstPlay = true;
```

Playing a video should update `playCount` only during the first play.
(*eg:* future pauses will skip the *"IF"* code):

**(2)** Replace function `playVideo()` code with this new version:

```
function playVideo() 
{
    if( is_FirstPlay == true )
    {
        playCount++;
        updatePlayCount();
        savePlayCount();
        is_FirstPlay = false;   
    }
    
    videoElement.play();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. Am I to replace my let playCounts = []; variable with the let playCount; let is_First Play = true; variable? And do the same with the function playVideo? Or just add them into the code in addition?

Comment: Yes replace both parts with the shown example code.

Comment: Fortunately the play count doesn't increase after pressing pause then play again, but unfortunately the play count won't increase at all when pressing play now.